# How can I change an SVG color without using an ID in the SVG file itself?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Newbie to working with SVGs and I've run into a problem. Basically I'm using the Noun Project API pro version ( https://api.thenounproject.com/ ) to scrape icons as SVGs. Right now, I save the SVGs in a local folder. I want to be able to change the color of the icon (right now they download as black, and I want to change the color). I am loading the SVGs via the  tag with a reference to the folder where the SVGs are being saved. I know it's fairly simple to change the color using vanilla JS (using document.getElementById('svgObject').contentDocument, and then accessing the inner document using a unique id). The problem is that the SVGs I save don't have any ID, and I don't know how to give them an ID. Right now, I'm looping through the folder and displaying the folder contents in a webpage. That's all working fine, but I can't manage to figure out how to change the color.

Basically, I just want all the icons in the folder to be set to a different color (for example, they could all be set to "red." They don't need to each have a different color). How do I do that without specifying the actual ID (since the SVG doesn't include an ID upon download), or else how do I add an ID to the SVG tag itself?

Comment: Have you tried using the `fill` attribute? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/fill

Comment: could you use `css` and do `svg { color: red }`?

Comment: do you want the color to be changed for all instances or only on some pages?

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering so quickly! :) @goto1 I definitely do need to use the fill attribute, but I'm not sure how to specify the SVG itself

Comment: @NidhinJoseph All instances! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a bunch of `svg`s on your page and you'd like to change the color of each to the same color, you could do the following:

```js
function changeSvgColors() {
  const svgs = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')

  for (let i = 0; i < svgs.length; i++) {
    svgs[i].setAttribute('fill', 'red')
  }
}
```

This will loop through every `svg` on your page and set their `fill` attribute to `red`.

Essentially, this is equivalent to doing this:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 512 512" fill="red">
  ...
</svg>
```

Here's a quick demo:

- [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/35z1a2ct/)

---

Alternatively, if you're using something like the `img` tag to load your `svg`s onto your page, using `object` instead would let you do the same thing as above.

Assuming your `html` looks like the following:

```html
<div>
  <object
    data="http://localhost:5000/image.svg"
    type="image/svg+xml"
  ></object>
</div>
```

Then,

```js
function changeSvgColors() {
  const objects = document.getElementsByTagName('object')

  for (let i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
    const object = objects[i]
    const svg = object.contentDocument.rootElement

    svg.setAttribute('fill', 'red')
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh my gosh, you saved me here!! Thank you so much, worked like a charm <3 excellent work, you've got my vote :)

Answer (score 1):

One option would be using the svg as an image (or as an object if you prefer) and filters to change the color.

```css
#theImage{filter: invert(27%) sepia(51%) saturate(2878%) hue-rotate(346deg) brightness(104%) contrast(97%);}
```

```html
<img id="theImage" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/bone300.svg" >
```

Please read this article: [Solved with CSS! Colorizing SVG Backgrounds](https://css-tricks.com/solved-with-css-colorizing-svg-backgrounds/)

Yet another option is using the svg as a mask. Keep in mind that the support for mask is not that good.

```css
#theDiv{
  display: inline-block;
  width:300px;
  height:134px;
  -webkit-mask: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/bone300.svg);
  mask: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/bone300.svg);
  mask-size: cover;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="theDiv"></div>
```

But **the best option** would be to use the svg inline. You may save all your icons in a root svg element with width="0"; height="0"; position="absolute". Next you can use the icons with `<use>` and you change the color using the fill attribute `<use fill="red" xlink:href=".....` or styling it in CSS

Answer (score 0):

You can give the SVGs a `class` instead of an `id` & set the color using javascript's `getElementsByClassName`

This Mozilla article explains:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Answer (score 0):

Your best shot in achiveing this is to make use of the `fill` attibute for svg elements. Now, you can work this out two ways

**Method 1:**
Using `img` tag like this `<img src="your_file.svg" />`. In this case, you will need to edit the file directly, and that's it, it should reflect everywhere you reference the svg.

**Method 2:**
You can use svg as inline like below. The advantage in this approach is that if you have varying instance of the same svg, then this is the way to go. On the other side, if your svg stays same throughout the app, this goes against the [DRY principle](https://dzone.com/articles/software-design-principles-dry-and-kiss).

```css
svg {
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <path d="M25,7l28,36l40-18l-36,25l19,44l-27-37l-41,17l36-26z" fill="#cfc"/>
  <ellipse cx="50" cy="50" rx="32" ry="30" stroke="#fc0" fill="none" stroke-width="11"/>
  <path d="M63,2l-7,43l42,17l-45-6l-16,42l7,-45l-42-16l45,6z" fill="#3cc"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind having the svg all one color, you could set the `fill` attribute of the svg to `currentcolor`. Then it will take on the color of the element that it is in.

```css
#span1 {
  color: red;
}

#span2 {
  color: blue;
}

#span3 {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <span id=span1>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 200 200" width="150" height="150" fill-rule="evenodd" fill="currentcolor">
      <title>HTML5 Logo</title>
      <path d="M12,0 188,0 172,180 100,200 28,180Z M45,37 156,37 154,59 69,59 71,81 152,81 146,149 100,162 54,149 52,114 74,114 76,132 100,139 124,132 127,103 51,103Z"/>
  </svg>
  </span>
  <span id=span2>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 200 200" width="150" height="150" fill-rule="evenodd" fill="currentcolor">
      <title>HTML5 Logo</title>
      <path d="M12,0 188,0 172,180 100,200 28,180Z M45,37 156,37 154,59 69,59 71,81 152,81 146,149 100,162 54,149 52,114 74,114 76,132 100,139 124,132 127,103 51,103Z"/>
  </svg>
  </span>
  <span id=span3>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 200 200" width="150" height="150" fill-rule="evenodd" fill="currentcolor">
      <title>HTML5 Logo</title>
      <path d="M12,0 188,0 172,180 100,200 28,180Z M45,37 156,37 154,59 69,59 71,81 152,81 146,149 100,162 54,149 52,114 74,114 76,132 100,139 124,132 127,103 51,103Z"/>
  </svg>
  </span>
</body>
```